# Magento 2 How change ID for order?

Tags: magento2, orders, increment-id, prefix, id

I have order with ID = 00000188

```
UPDATE `sales_sequence_profile` SET `prefix` = '9' WHERE `sales_sequence_profile`.`profile_id` = 1;
```

And now my order ID = 900000188

But I want change to this format 000009188, how do I do it?

if i run ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=000009188; my order after this value 000009999 will become 0000010000, but i want see 00000910000

Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the sequence number from the table

```
sequence_order_[store_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order sequence with the following steps.

> Step 1 : Find the order sequence table by store id. in my case order
> sequence table for store ID 1 is : sequence_order_StoreID table
>
> ```
> EX : sequence_order_1 // 1 is store id
> ```
>
> Step 2 : Now we need to start order id with this sequence(000009188)
> then execute below ALTER query.
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=000009188;
> ```

Also note that you need to remove prefix column value 9 from the sequence profile database table if not require.

Comment: if i run ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=000009188;  my order after this value 000009999 will become 0000010000, but i want see 00000910000

Comment: So for that you need to set the prefix column value as '000009' in the sales_sequence_profile table. Also, use the below query to set the auto-increment. ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9999; Now your new order id is Prefix + Auto Increment Value. for ex :  0000099999,00000910000 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You may try to run the following query:

> ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 000009188;

I believe that's what you're looking for.